# How to write an intersection function for any kind of shapes

Tags: c++, freeglut

I have to write a function, which detects intersection and returns true or false.

I have Shape.cpp file, and rectangle.cpp, circle.cpp files inherits of it. I tried to calculate it, but i failed. There is no error, but when my program starts, it crashes. MY Question is why it crashes? is my way wrongs? Here is circle.cpp file.

```
bool Circ::intersects(Shape* pshape)
{
    Rect *p1 = dynamic_cast<Rect*>(pshape);
    Circ *p2 = dynamic_cast<Circ*>(pshape);

    if(p1)
    {
        float circleDistance_x = abs(p2->getPos().x - p1->getPos().x);
        float circleDistance_y = abs(p2->getPos().y - p1->getPos().y);

        if(circleDistance_x > (p1->getSize().x/2 + p2->getRad()))
            return false;
        if(circleDistance_y > (p1->getSize().y/2 + p2->getRad()))
            return false;
        if(circleDistance_x <= (p1->getSize().x/2))
            return true;
        if(circleDistance_y <= (p1->getSize().y/2))
            return true;
        float cornerDistance_sq = (circleDistance_x - (p1->getSize().x/2)) + (circleDistance_y - (p1->getSize().y/2))*(circleDistance_y - (p1->getSize().y/2));

        return (cornerDistance_sq <= p2->getRad()^2);

    }

    return false;
}
```

This is not the code all i want to write. But when it fails, i stopped to write.

and my Shapes.h file

```
    #ifndef _SHAPES_H
#define _SHAPES_H


struct Point2d
{
    float x, y;

};
struct Point3d
{
    float r, g, b;

};

class Shape
{
protected:
    bool m_bMarked;
    Point3d m_col;
    Point2d m_veldir;
    Point2d m_pos;
    float m_vel;
public:
    Shape(Point2d& pos, Point2d& veldir, float vel, Point3d& col)
        :m_pos(pos),m_veldir(veldir),m_vel(vel),m_col(col)
    {
        m_bMarked = false;
     }
    virtual ~Shape() {}
    virtual void draw() = 0;
    virtual bool intersects(Shape*) = 0;
    inline void move() { m_pos.x += m_veldir.x*m_vel; m_pos.y += m_veldir.y*m_vel; }
    inline void invert_xdir() { m_veldir.x *= -1; }
    inline void invert_ydir() { m_veldir.y *= -1; }
    inline void MarkShape() { m_bMarked = true; }
    inline void UnMarkShape() { m_bMarked = false; }
    inline bool isMarked() { return m_bMarked; }
    inline void increase_vel() { m_vel += 0.01f; }
    inline void decrease_vel() { m_vel -= 0.01f; }

};


#endif
```

And finally my ShapesMain.cpp file

```
#include <time.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>   
#include <cmath>

#include "Rectangle.h"
#include "Circle.h"


// YOU CAN CHANGE THE NUMBER OF SHAPES 
#define SHAPE_COUNT 20

// YOU CAN MODIFY WINDOW SIZE BY CHANGING THESE
// YOU MAY ALSO VIEW WINDOW IN FULL SCREEN
#define WINDOWX 500
#define WINDOWY 500

// UNCOMMENT THE LINE BELOW TO STOP MOVING SHAPES
//#define NO_MOTION

// CHANGE THESE DIMENSIONS HOWEVER YOU LIKE
#define MAX_SHAPE_DIM 70
#define MIN_SHAPE_DIM 10

float g_windowWidth = WINDOWX;
float g_windowHeight = WINDOWY;

Shape*  g_shapeList[SHAPE_COUNT];
int     g_numShapes = 0;
bool    g_bShowIntersection = true;



//------------------------------------

void Initialize()
{
    srand ( time(NULL) );

    // delete previous shapes, if there is any
    if (g_numShapes > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < g_numShapes; i++)
            delete g_shapeList[i];
    }

    // create a new shape repository
    do {
        g_numShapes = rand() % SHAPE_COUNT; // number of shapes are randomly determined     
    } while (g_numShapes < 5); // we dont want to have less than 5 shapes


    int rect_count = g_numShapes * (rand() % 10 / 10.0f);
    int circle_count =  g_numShapes - rect_count;

    int half_wind_x = 3* g_windowWidth / 4;
    int half_wind_y = 3* g_windowHeight / 4;
    int max_dim = MAX_SHAPE_DIM; // max dim. of any shape 
    int min_dim = MIN_SHAPE_DIM; // min dim. of any shape
    int quad_wind = g_windowWidth / 4;

    for (int i= 0; i<g_numShapes; i++)
    {

        float x, y;
        float v1, v2;

        // set positions 
        do {
            x = rand() % half_wind_x;
        } while (x <= quad_wind);

        do {
            y = rand() % half_wind_y;
        } while (y <= quad_wind);
        Point2d pos = { x,y };

        // set velocity directions 
        do{
            v1 = rand() % 10 / 10.0f;
            v2 = rand() % 10 / 10.0f;           
        } while (v1 == 0 || v2 == 0);

        v1 *= (rand() % 2) ? -1 : 1;
        v2 *= (rand() % 2) ? -1 : 1;
        float vnorm = sqrt(v1*v1 + v2*v2);
        Point2d veldir = { v1 / vnorm, v2 / vnorm };

        // set velocity 
        float vel;
        do {
            vel = rand() % 2 / 10.0f;
        } while (vel == 0);

#ifdef NO_MOTION
        vel = 0.0f;
#endif
        //set color 
        float R = rand()%100/100.0f;
        float G = rand()%100/100.0f;
        float B = rand()%100/100.0f;
        Point3d color = { R,G,B };

        // construct objects
        if (i < rect_count)
        {
            float wx;
            float wy;
            do {
                wx = rand() % quad_wind;
            } while (wx < min_dim || wx>max_dim);

            do {
                wy = rand() % quad_wind;
            } while (wy < min_dim || wy>max_dim);

            Point2d size = { wx, wy };          

            Rect* pRect = new Rect(pos, size, veldir, vel, color);
            g_shapeList[i] = pRect;
        }
        else
        {
            float rad;
            do {
                rad = rand() % quad_wind;
            } while (rad < min_dim || rad>max_dim);


            Circ* pCirc = new Circ(pos, rad, veldir, vel, color);
            g_shapeList[i] = pCirc;
        }
    }

    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

}
//-------------------------------------
// This function handles the intersections of shapes. 
// if the user is not interested in marking intersections
// s/he can set bMarkIntersections to false..in this case
// no intersection test is performed
void MarkObjects(bool bMarkIntersections)
{
    if (bMarkIntersections == false)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < g_numShapes; i++)
            g_shapeList[i]->UnMarkShape();
    }
    else
    {
        // reset the states of all shapes as unmarked
        for (int i = 0; i < g_numShapes; i++)
            g_shapeList[i]->UnMarkShape();

        for (int i = 0; i < g_numShapes; i++)
        {           
            for (int j = i+1; j < g_numShapes; j++)
            {

                if (g_shapeList[i]->intersects(g_shapeList[j]))
                {
                    g_shapeList[i]->MarkShape();
                    g_shapeList[j]->MarkShape();

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
//------------------------------------
void UpdateData()
{
    // create viewport bounding rectangles to keep the shapes within the viewport
    Point2d Winpos = { -1.0,0.0 };
    Point2d Winsize = { 1.0 , g_windowHeight };
    Point2d Winveldir = { 0,0 }; // dummy veldir
    float Winvel = 0.0f; //not moving
    Point3d Wincol = { 0,0,0 }; // dummy color
    Rect WindowRectLeft(Winpos, Winsize, Winveldir, Winvel, Wincol);
    Winpos.x = 0.0; Winpos.y = -1.0;
    Winsize.x = g_windowWidth; Winsize.y = 1.0;
    Rect WindowRectBottom(Winpos, Winsize, Winveldir, Winvel, Wincol);
    Winpos.x = g_windowWidth; Winpos.y = 0.0;
    Winsize.x = 1; Winsize.y = g_windowHeight;
    Rect WindowRectRight(Winpos, Winsize, Winveldir, Winvel, Wincol);
    Winpos.x = 0.0; Winpos.y = g_windowHeight;
    Winsize.x = g_windowWidth; Winsize.y = 1.0f;
    Rect WindowRectUp(Winpos, Winsize, Winveldir, Winvel, Wincol);

    for (int i = 0; i < g_numShapes; i++)
    {
        // move the shape
        g_shapeList[i]->move();

        // if it bounces to the window walls, invert its veldir
        if (g_shapeList[i]->intersects(&WindowRectLeft) ||
            g_shapeList[i]->intersects(&WindowRectRight))
            g_shapeList[i]->invert_xdir();

        if (g_shapeList[i]->intersects(&WindowRectBottom) ||
            g_shapeList[i]->intersects(&WindowRectUp))
            g_shapeList[i]->invert_ydir();
    }
}
//------------------------------------
void ChangeSize(GLsizei w, GLsizei h)
{
    if(h == 0)
        h = 1;

    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    g_windowHeight = h;
    g_windowWidth = w;

    glOrtho(0, g_windowWidth, 0, g_windowHeight , 1.0f, -1.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
//------------------------------------
void processNormalKeys(unsigned char key, int x, int y) 
{

    if (key == 'q') // PRESS 'q' to terminate the application
        exit(0);
    if(key=='r') // PRESS 'r' ket to reset the shapes
        Initialize();
    if (key == 's') // toggle between showing the intersections or not
        g_bShowIntersection = g_bShowIntersection ? false: true;


}
//------------------------------------
void processSpecialKeys(int key, int x, int y) 
{

    switch(key) {
        case GLUT_KEY_LEFT :                
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT :       
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_UP:   
            // PRESSING UP ARROW KEY INCREASES THE SHAPE VELOCITIES
            for (int i = 0; i < g_numShapes; i++)
                g_shapeList[i]->increase_vel();
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
            // PRESSING DOWN ARROW KEY DECREASES THE SHAPE VELOCITIES
            for (int i = 0; i < g_numShapes; i++)
                g_shapeList[i]->decrease_vel();

            break;
    }

}

//-------------------------------------
void display() {


    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   // Clear the color buffer

    glEnable(GL_BLEND); glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    UpdateData();
    MarkObjects(g_bShowIntersection);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    for (int i= 0; i<g_numShapes; i++)
        g_shapeList[i]->draw();


    glutSwapBuffers();
}
//------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   

    glutInit(&argc, argv);          // Initialize GLUT
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB );
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(WINDOWX, WINDOWY);



    glutCreateWindow("COM102B - PA4");  


    // Register callback handler for window re-paint
    glutDisplayFunc(display);       
    glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);
    glutIdleFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(processNormalKeys);
    glutSpecialFunc(processSpecialKeys);

    Initialize();


    glutMainLoop();                 // Enter infinitely event-processing loop

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The shapes move in the window and you want to know when they overlap each other? if so, you have to track the area the shape is in and then compare if that area is being occupied by any other shape. You could define a "grid" in the window and calculate where is each shape if two or more shapes are occupying the same grid coordinate, well, they intersect. well, that is how I would attack the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in these lines:

```
Rect *p1 = dynamic_cast<Rect*>(pshape);
Circ *p2 = dynamic_cast<Circ*>(pshape);
```

Unless you had inherited Rect from Circ or vice versa this is what makes your program crash, you can't cast your pShape to Circ if it is a Rect, so when you pass a Rect object to your function it will correctly cast to Rect* but it will fail with Circ* returning nullptr, so then when you try to access methods from p2 it will crash becouse you are accessing to invalid memory (0x00000000) :

```
    if(p1)
        {
            float circleDistance_x = abs(p2->getPos().x - p1->getPos().x);
            float circleDistance_y = abs(p2->getPos().y - p1->getPos().y);

            if(circleDistance_x > (p1->getSize().x/2 + p2->getRad()))
                return false;
            if(circleDistance_y > (p1->getSize().y/2 + p2->getRad()))
                return false;
            if(circleDistance_x <= (p1->getSize().x/2))
                return true;
            if(circleDistance_y <= (p1->getSize().y/2))
                return true;
            float cornerDistance_sq = (circleDistance_x - (p1->getSize().x/2)) + (circleDistance_y - (p1->getSize().y/2))*(circleDistance_y - (p1->getSize().y/2));

            return (cornerDistance_sq <= p2->getRad()^2);

        }
```

So, you could simply just cast the first p1 pointer since the method is from circle, it's obvious that it was called from a Circ Object so there's no need for p2 pointer.

```
    Rect *p1 = dynamic_cast<Rect*>(pshape);
    if(p1)
        {
            float circleDistance_x = abs(getPos().x - p1->getPos().x);
            float circleDistance_y = abs(getPos().y - p1->getPos().y);

            if(circleDistance_x > (p1->getSize().x/2 + getRad()))
                return false;
            if(circleDistance_y > (p1->getSize().y/2 + getRad()))
                return false;
            if(circleDistance_x <= (p1->getSize().x/2))
                return true;
            if(circleDistance_y <= (p1->getSize().y/2))
                return true;
            float cornerDistance_sq = (circleDistance_x - (p1->getSize().x/2)) + (circleDistance_y - (p1->getSize().y/2))*(circleDistance_y - (p1->getSize().y/2));

            return (cornerDistance_sq <= getRad()^2);

        }
```

Also on the line:

```
return (cornerDistance_sq <= getRad()^2)
```

i think you are trying to get the radius square but this wont do it, what it is actually doing is

```
(cornerDistance_sq <= getRad()) ^ 2
```

becouse <= has greater precedence to ^, plus ^ is not a square operator it is a bitwise operator. So what you actually want is :

```
 return cornerDistance_sq <= getRad() * getRad();
```